# How to update field values of a content type's nodes when when viewing a particular content type page

Tags: entities, hooks, nodes, theming

I'd essentially like to alter the values of a specific custom field of a few of nodes before they're displayed in a view on the 'page' of a specific content type.

The content type is that will be displayed is a ***park***. When a park is viewed, one of the blocks shown is a view that fetches and shows several nodes that are also '*parks*'.

This *park* content type has a field called ***proximity***. I'd like to change the value of proximity (based on a mathematical formula) for all parks before the view is processed, so that I can use *proximity* in the view.

From what I understand so far, I should use a `park_preprocess` function, which calls some sort of `hook` to change the *proximity* values. Is this correct, and how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pushinder and Shirin for responding, and providing the start I needed! However both answers were lacking the detail I needed. I won't paste my entire code here, as it's too long, but I'll describe what I used and why:

- `hook_node_view` was the right hook to call my function at the right time - before page load
- `$refN = $node->field_location_n[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];` and the same for East were required to get the reference coordinates
- Because I have several hundred nodes with coordinates, I couldn't load each one individually using `load_node` or collectively using `load_node_multiple` since this used far too many resources for every page load
- Instead, I used `db_query` and `field_attach_load` together, as described in this answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/30906/20264 to effectively load just the values I needed
- I then used `foreach( $nodes as $nodei ) {` to loop through all the results
- `$distance = sqrt( pow( $refN - $nodeiN, 2 ) + pow( $refE - $nodeiE, 2 ) );` was my proximity calculation
- Then, only for results with a specified proximity would I update `$node`
- Since I was using the *Entity Reference* module to record 'Nearby places' in my nodes, I used the following to update the entity references:

  $node->field_nearby[LANGUAGE_NONE][$i] = array( "target_id" => $nodei->nid );

Answer (score 0):

[hook_node_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) will be used in this scenario.

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if($node->type == 'park' && $view_mode == 'full')
   {
    /* change the value of proximity here after applying your formula. 
      * Here you have complete node array, so you alter the result easily here.
    */

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) as @Pushpinder Rana said.but if you want to modify a field you should save your node.here i simply plus one my proximity field on my hook.

```
/**
 * Impelement hook_node_view
 * @param type $node
 * @param type $view_mode
 * @param type $langcode
 */
function MODULENAME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    //plus one proximity field and save a node
    $new_value = $node->field_proximity[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] + 1;
    $node->field_proximity[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $new_value;
    node_submit($node);
    node_save($node);
    // here is to show user updated proximity value;    
    $node->content['field_proximity'][0]['#markup'] = $new_value;
    }
```

Comment: Can this be called from within template.php in my theme, or must I create a module to implement this?

Comment: Drupal themes can only implement theme functions (which include template preprocess and process functions) or alter hooks[https://www.drupal.org/node/254940#theme_alter]. You should create a module to call this hook.